# Android Implementing Chat Bubble in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am in the process of writing a chat client on Android but I am having some issues with putting a chat bubble in my client.  My chat screen consists of a `ListView` with a textbox and a Send button at bottom.  For an outgoing message, the texts are left aligned in the `ListView` row. For an incoming message, the texts are right aligned in the `ListView` row. However, the chat bubble does not resize to the length of the incoming message texts.  This issue does not happen for the left aligned outgoing message.

Here the screen shot is below.

[image]

The chat message texts are stored in a database and are displayed in the `ListView` via a cursor adapter.  The alignment of the chat texts are determined on-the-fly in the Java source code in `MessageAdapter`.  Both chat bubbles are done using nine patch image of Android.

Below is my chat activity layout, the `ListView` with issue is `messageHistoryList`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dip" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/messageHistoryList"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="0px" 
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

      <Button 
          android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="4"
          android:text="Send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userAndMessage">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textUser"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textMessage"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textTime"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Message adapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    static final String[] FROM = { ChatHistoryManager.C_TIME };
    static final int[] TO = { R.id.textTime };

    static final int MESSAGE_INCOMING_DIR = 1;

    private String incomingMessageUserName;
    private String selfUserName;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, R.layout.message_list_item, cursor, FROM, TO);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(row, context, cursor);

        int messageDir = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistoryManager.C_DIR));
        if(messageDir == MESSAGE_INCOMING_DIR) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams userNameAndChatMessageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            userNameAndChatMessageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams userNameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            userNameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.textMessage);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams chatMessageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            chatMessageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, R.id.textUser);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams timeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            timeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.userAndMessage);
            timeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.userAndMessage);

            row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);

            // Set the chat message
            String chatMessage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistoryManager.C_TEXT));
            TextView textMessage = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
            textMessage.setText(chatMessage.trim());
            textMessage.setLayoutParams(chatMessageParams);

            // Format the time stamp of the message
            long timestamp = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistoryManager.C_TIME));
            TextView textTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
            String readableTimeStamp = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp);
            textTime.setText(readableTimeStamp.trim());
            textTime.setLayoutParams(timeParams);

            // Format the message owner and the message
            TextView textUser = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
            textUser.setText(incomingMessageUserName + ": ");
            textUser.setLayoutParams(userNameParams);
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.incoming_chat_bubble);
        }
        else {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams userNameAndChatMessageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            userNameAndChatMessageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.userImage);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams userImageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            userImageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams userNameParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            userNameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.userAndMessage);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams chatMessageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            chatMessageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.textUser);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams timeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            timeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.userAndMessage);
            timeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.userAndMessage);

            // Set the chat message
            String chatMessage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistoryManager.C_TEXT));
            TextView textMessage = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
            textMessage.setText(chatMessage);
            textMessage.setLayoutParams(chatMessageParams);

            // Format the time stamp of the message
            long timestamp = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistoryManager.C_TIME));
            TextView textTime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
            textTime.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp));
            textTime.setLayoutParams(timeParams);

            // Format the message owner and the message
            TextView textUser = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textUser);
            textUser.setText(selfUserName + ": ");
            textUser.setLayoutParams(userNameParams);
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outgoing_chat_bubble);
        }
    }

    public void setIncomingMessageUserName(String inputUserName) {
        this.incomingMessageUserName = inputUserName;
    }

    public void setSelfUserName(String inputUserName) {
        this.selfUserName = inputUserName;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "chat bubble"?

Comment: Chat bubble is bubble in comic book that contains character's words.  Some people call it speech bubble.  Android app like eBuddy uses it when you are chatting with your friend.

Comment: did you find the solution of this?

Comment: Hai iam also doing same application i have tried a lot but iam not geeting how to set different colors for sending and reciving msgs can u please help me in this

Comment: I've written a blogpost about [chat bubbles in android](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html), you can find source code there too.

Comment: check my question about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11202206/1056359

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672208/layout-chat-bubbles-issues-textview-fills-all-the-screen

Comment: Check out this project https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837692/how-to-create-a-chat-activity-with-the-time-stamp-in-bubble/31211428#31211428).

Answer (score 5):

use LinearLayout instead of Relative layout. It will solve your problem. I had same issue. I solved it using LinearLayout