# How to create a chat activity with the time stamp in bubble

Tags: android, android-listview, timestamp, chat

I want to create a chat activity in which user can send and receive messages.
Sender messages on right in bubble with time stamp and received messages on left in buble with time stamp.

What I have done so far is that I have created  a chat application its working fine, i get my messages on right and received messages on left but I don't know how to add time stamp in bubble just like whatsapp.

Please help its very important for me.

Answer (score 1):

use following code to get current time :

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();
 System.out.println(df.format(calobj.getTime()));
```

Comment: i know how to get time.....but iam not getting how to put time in same bubble like in whatsapp

Comment: you have to make custom adapter and use custom listview for that

Comment: Done it..but i cant add time stamp in chat bubble...can you tell me how to do this.. i have followed up this project
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/

Comment: 1. add view in the xml  where you want the time
2. get a reference to it in the java class related to the activity
3. parse a String according to the answer above 
4. attach this string from #3 to the view you have a reference for

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe someone still needs it. Please consider that the in the following scenario I set the `gravity` and the `textAlignment` programmatically, depending on the position of the bubble, left or right.
This is how I managed to do this:

#### Normal View

[image: Normal View]

#### Layout boundaries enabled

[image: Layout boundaries enabled]

#### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_wrapper"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/message_wrapper"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="9sp"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Other info

The background is a 9-patch image that I set programmatically, can be found with a simple search. Tested on:

- Samsung Galaxy S4
- Android 22.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the code from the androidhive link
you have to change following two layout files

```
list_item_message_right.xml. 
list_item_message_left.xml.
```

add a new textview for timestamp in above layout files and then set their values time stamp values in `MessageListAdapter` class

```
    lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());

//set time stamp here
```