# Create Linear Layout Dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml

Basically, I read messages from firebase database one by one in a loop after which, I want to add each message to the linear layout.

I have a Linear Layout XML file like this called my_linear_layout
[image: IMAGE SAMPLE]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="MESSAGE GOES HERE. IT CAN BE A LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG MESSAGE"
    android:textColor="#000" />


<ImageView

    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:src="@drawable/senduser" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, want to inflate this layout in my Activity's Relative Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".BuyerChat">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
    layout="@layout/type_message_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can not just add the code here because I want to have n number of linear layouts, depending on how many messages I have. Basically, I read messages from firebase database after which, I want to add each message to the linear layout.

So, I want a code snippet that will allow me to add a linear layout everytime I call it and place a new message in linear layout every time.

I have been at this for quite some time, please help.

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: @Selvin I tried the method shown here:http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115
But, I don't know how to set layout and text view width as wrap_content or match_parent through java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BuyerChat">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        layout="@layout/type_message_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity:

```
LinearLayout dynamicHolder = (LineraLayout) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_holder);

for(int i = 0; i<your_message_length; i++){
    View dynamicView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_linear_layout, null, false);
    TextView yourTextView = (TextView) dynamicView.findViewById(R.id.your_tv_id);//give id to your textview in my_linear_layout
    youtTextView.setText(your_each_message_from_db);

    dynamicHolder.addView(dynamicView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using linear layout instead of listview.
ListView is strongly recommended in this case.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pmf2tH4A5Y) how efficient are listViews compared to linearLayout.
Plus its easier to use.
ListViews do not inflate all items, they inflate however many can fit on a page at a time. Your fastest option, with or without paging is a ListView.

Please see here how to get started with the listView for chat application.
[Simple chat application using listview in android](https://trinitytuts.com/simple-chat-application-using-listview-in-android/)

I would suggest you to create Custom adapter for ListView. You just need to check the condition to change the background of layout/views inside getViews() method.

Some thread may be helpful to you:

[The World of List View](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf)
[Android Implementing Chat Bubble in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704436/android-implementing-chat-bubble-in-listview)